# How to access text/paragraphs from PowerPoints using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

How do you get/read text content from text boxes inside of PowerPoint?

Comment: please have at least a glimpse at the [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/index.html) first and then show some effort before asking questions here.

Comment: I did :) But the concept of slides is bit more complicated :) With MS word we can simply use getText whereas with slides i'm not sure what to ask for. There are many examples with images but nothing about text.